# What are the parity of particles?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, parity, mesons

When looking to see if particle collisions/decays are possible and what force they act through, how do you know the [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28physics%29) of particles to know whether they act through weak force? Is there a grouping where for example mesons are one parity and quarks are another?

Comment: Another example: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57062/44126

Comment: I'm not looking for any mathematical method, just a general principle of grouping.

Comment: There isn't a general principle. There are positive- and negative-parity mesons, positive- and negative-parity baryons, positive- and negative-parity nuclear ground and excited states, and positive- and negative-parity atomic ground and excited states. Also while weak decays may violate intrinsic parity (as in the "tau-theta puzzle"), just as important are parity-violating angular correlations: the distribution of beta particles from a polarized source found by Wu (1957), the polarization of neutrinos found by Goldhaber (1950), and the polarization of beta electrons found by Cox (1927).